# Decompile ipsw?

Tags: ios5

How do hackers decompile ipsw files and read the code ?
Recently I read an update that some hacker was able to find out about jabber and aim services integrated in new versions of ios. 
How did he do that ?

Answer (score 2):

First off, it is a IPA file. Every app is a IPA file. IPSW is the iOS file type.
He did not get the full code, he probably just jailbreaks his phone, looks in the file directory of the phone that you can only see when jailbroken and looks for any new files.
He most likely saw a name like AIM.plist or something like that.

This really isn't a coding question and more of a hacking questions in general for the iPhone.